# Write UDP data to CSV in Python?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, udp, ascii

DISCLAIMER: I am a total Python n00b and have never ever written anything in Python, I haven't programmed anything in years, and the last language I learned was Visual Basic 6.  So bear with me!

So I have an Android app that transmits my phone's sensor (accelerometer, magnet, light etc) data to my Windows PC via UDP, and I have a Python 3.3 script to display that data on screen, and write it to a CSV:

```
#include libraries n stuff
import socket
import traceback
import csv

#assign variables n stuff
host = ''
port = 5555
csvf = 'accelerometer.csv'

#do UDP stuff
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

#do CSV stuff
with open(csvf, 'w', newline='', encoding='ascii') as csv_handle:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_handle, delimiter=',')
    while 1:
        try:
            message, address = s.recvfrom(8192) 
            print(message)                      #display data on screen
            csv_writer.writerow(message)        #write data to CSV
        except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):  
            raise
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

The data on screen looks like this, which is correct:

```
b'7407.75961, 3, 0.865, 1.423, 9.022, 5,
```

The data in the CSV file looks like the numerical values of the ASCII codes of the data (note: codes won't match with above because data is slightly different):

```
57,48,48,50,46,54,51,57,57,57,44,32,51,44,32,32,32,48,46,53,52,57,44,32,32,53,46,54,56,56,44,32,32,56,46,51,53,53
```

How can I get my CSV to just write the string that the UDP socket is receiving?  I tried adding "encoding='ascii'", as you can see, but that didn't make a difference from leaving it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow` expects a sequence or iterable of values. But you just have one value.

The reason it sort of works, but does the wrong thing, is that your one value—a `bytes` string—is actually itself a sequence. But it's not a sequence of the comma-separated values, it's a sequence of bytes.

So, how do you get a sequence of the separate values?

---

One option is to use `split`. Either `message.split(b', ')` or `map(str.strip, message.split(b','))` seems reasonable here. That will give you this sequence:

```
[b'7407.75961', b'3', b'0.865', b'1.423', b'9.022', b'5']
```

---

But really, this is exactly what the `csv` module is for. You can, e.g., wrap the input in a `BytesIO` and pass it to a `csv.reader`, and then you just copy rows from that `reader` to the `writer`.

---

But if you think about it, you're getting data in `csv` format, and you want to write it out in the exact same `csv` format, without using it in any other way… so you don't even *need* the `csv` module here. Just use a plain old binary file:

```
with open(csvf, 'wb') as csv_handle:
    while True:
        try:
            message, address = s.recvfrom(8192) 
            print(message)                      #display data on screen
            csv_handle.write(message + b'\n')
        except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): 
            raise
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

---

While we're at it, you almost never need to do this:

```
except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): 
    raise
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

The only exceptions in Python 3.x that don't inherit from `Exception` are `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, `GeneratorExit` (which can't happen here), and any third-party exceptions that go out of their way to act like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`. So, just do this:

```
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Cool, that's probably a better method!  Now just two more things to do if anyone feels like helping me code them: 1: Don't write spaces, it confuses Excel when importing the CSV, so replace the spaces in the UDP data with nulls?  2: How to write to the file periodically, in case of PC crash?  This program is going to be running for 8 hours, generating a 30mb CSV file!  A) it probably won't work if I try to write it all at once at the end, and b) that's not a very reliable way to do things.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: (1) Well, nulls (`'\0'`) would confuse Excel even more… but empty strings, yes. Make sure `message.replace(', ', ',')` actually does remove all the right spaces and nothing else… If something that simple works, use it. If it's too quirky to get right on the first try, I'd go back to using `csv` to parse it and `csv` again to write it out in the different row format that Excel wants.

Comment: (2) Either way, you're already writing to the file periodically, not all at the end. However, if you don't call `flush` or `close`, those writes may get lost during a crash. So, just call `flush` after each time write—or after each N writes, or if X seconds have passed since the last flush, or whatever seems the best tradeoff between performance and robustness. (You could instead open and close the file each time, or even write a new copy and then move it over the original each time—that guarantees that you can't end up with half a line after a power failure—but that's probably overkill.)

Comment: (2 again) Your comment implies that you might want to just write periodically, instead writing every time you get a message. That could improve performance, but it makes things more complicated, and it means you're risking more data loss. And the buffering that Python and your OS do is good enough that just writing immediately and holding off on the flushes will get you most of the performance benefits without most of the cost.

Comment: What is the default buffer in Python?  I didn't test it for very long yet, but I went up to 250kB and never once saw the file written (was pressing F5 in Windows Explorer to check) until I closed the program.

Comment: @user2548740: I believe that the default is the file's `st_blksize` if that's available, falling back to the filesystem-wide parameter if not, falling back to a value determined at configure/build time if that's not available. It's probably around 16K. But keep in mind that MSVCRT, Windows, and/or NTFS are _also_ buffering. And Windows will take advantage of the fact that it's not required to actually write to disk unless you flush the file, close it, or read from it.

Comment: @user2548740: For example, maybe Python has written 32 16K blocks; Windows has the last 16 in a write-back disk cache, and has only sent the first 16 to the filesystem as tentative writes. The filesystem has put the blocks on disk and journaled them, but it hasn't updated the file record yet. So, if you have a power-fault, nothing is actually in the file, 128K is in recoverable backup data, 128K never got written anywhere. And that's why you want to `flush` periodically—or, if it's not a performance problem, after each message.

Comment: @user2548740: Anyway, the point is: If flushing all the time is a performance problem in your program, don't bother batching up your writes; just write as you get things and batch up only the flushes. It gets you the same safety and performance tradeoffs, and it's a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
csv_writer.writerow([message])
```

`csv_writer.writerow` expects an iterable as it's first argument, which would be a list of comma-separated values. In your example the message is a string, which is iterable so the csv_writer writes each character into separate, comma-separated value.

Comment: hoooooray!  Thank you!!!!

I actually had:
    csv_writer.writerow(message.decode(encoding='ascii'))   
So I changed it to:
    csv_writer.writerow([message.decode(encoding='ascii')])   
and it worked!